# How can I generate toasts when a new notification arrives on Twitter, via UWP and Tweetinvi?

Tags: c#, twitter, uwp, tweetinvi

I'm developing an alternative UWP Twitter client, using C# and Tweetinvi. However, I have run into a snag. I want to use a background task of some description, combined with the Tweetinvi Streams API, to generate toasts whenever a new notification comes in via Twitter.

However, I'm struggling with this, primarily due to the strict constraints on UWP background tasks. If I can't run anything in a background task for more than 30 seconds, how am I supposed to check for new notifications via the Streams API? It appears that it needs to run constantly in the background to detect new data.

Comment: How you check the new notifications via the Streams API in foreground?

Comment: I check them in the foreground using a IUserStream, which raises an event when a new notification comes in. This event is raised as long as the app is running in the foreground, so I can launch a toast notification to handle it. However, I can't do the same thing in the background, because I can't keep a background task running for longer than 30 seconds.

Comment: Does anyone have an answer to this problem?